# H.265 support in jxbrowser

Tags: jxbrowser

I am aware that a custom JxBrowser build with H.264 support can be created:
https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013050-mp3-mp4-h-264

But what about H.265 (assuming a valid license is obtained)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JxBrowser is based on Chromium engine. According to the [official documentation](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video), Chromium doesn't support H.265 at the moment. When Chromium adds support of H.265, then it will be enabled in JxBrowser as well.